# how can i delete a single field in a document in couch db?

Tags: database, node.js, couchdb

I googled and searched in stackoverflow.There I find this :

```
db.get('id', function (err, doc) {
   var inside_key_values = doc.key_value_pair;

   delete inside_key_values[key_to_delete];

   db.merge("document", {
         key_value_pair: inside_key_values
        }, function (err, res) {
         console.log('New key value pairs saved')
      });

 });
```

In this,how can i replace doc.key_value_pair with my field.My field is like
tradeinfo : "Something that we enter",
Under  certain case I have to delete this field(Key - value pair).Is that above code works..?

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Have you tried it? Each time you want to update a document in CouchDB, you need to save the entire document again (a document cannot be modified in-place). So, make any modifications you need, then save it.

Answer (score 0):

according to [Nano](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano) official document, you can use insert method to override an existing document.

```
delete object.toRemoveField;
const result=await db.insert(object);//must contain _rev key so it can override the old one
```